# Assigning my own file path in reverse engineering

Tags: windows

I am working on reverse engineering and i wanted to give my own file path without using open dialog box like writing a fixed file path and read a file from that every time the software start.i tried to give the file name in a .data section of the software but it retrieve only the hex number not the string.

Is there any way hooking windows API for file open?or any way to write in memory and to read it every time the software starts?Any advice or direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand the question, especially the first paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

I think that what you may be looking for is "intercepting system call", quick google search came up with this link:
http://jbremer.org/intercepting-system-calls-on-x86_64-windows/ so it should be possible and not too difficult.

Basically if you manage to intercept a call to [GetOpenFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646927%28VS.85%29.aspx) and replace it with custom implementation you should be able to do what you want (that is put hardcoded file path to appropriate buffer in LPOPENFILENAME structure)

As for your attempt to modify compiled code (I assume that what you are referring as reverse engineering is disassembling and modifying binaries) it should be possible to do, but it will require deep knowledge of windows binary architecture and assembly language.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Note that it would be easier to patch out the `GetOpenFileName` call all together and simply perform an assignment to the variable holding the path or patch references to that variable to a hardcoded location.